# Saving and accessing SQL databases in Azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, backup

A friend of mine has 3 small SQL databases on her Azure account that she asked me to download for her. I said no problem…thinking she had a VM running with SQL Server and I could just RDC in and grab everything…no such luck and no FTP access.

I've done an export but have no idea how to download the .bacpac file.

I've logged in through the management portal - but there's no options in there to export/download anything.

Can someone tell me the best - easiest - way to save these databases? Is there an easy way to download them? If I configure a VM in her account can access them that way? Is there a way I can transfer them over to my account?

I don't know all that much about Blob storage and container management - I've seen a few instructions and they seem very complex to me just to download a .bacpac file so I'm assuming I'm missing something.

Any help or ideas would be great!

Thank you...

Rob

Comment: have a look at: http://www.jasonstrate.com/2013/04/restoring-azure-sql-database-to-a-local-server/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem.

Use a linked server connection between your on premise database and SQL AZURE.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/09/19/announcing-updates-to-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

Quick list of steps.

1 - Link to SQL Azure database.

2 - Script out objects.

http://craftydba.com/?p=4827

Check out how to manage Azure from SSMS on my blog.  Half way down, right click table, script as Create.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/24/10014071.aspx

How to script a whole database.

3 - Create mirror database on premise using scripts from step 2.

4 - Create linked server to AZURE database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx

5 - INSERT INTO  SELECT * FROM

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Why select * into does not work in Azure.  Might work with a linked server.  Never tried.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/05/04/select-into-with-sql-azure.aspx

6 - Watch out for constraints such as primary key on identity column.  You will have to enable identity insert.  Other constraints, you can disable.

7 - Re-enable constraints with checking.

Again, this whole process assumes you do not have a ton of data.  If you do, you might want to look into using a ETL tool such as SSIS.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time! But, unfortunately, you lost me at "script out objects"…. Actually, I don't even know how to link to SQL Azure DB.

Comment: I will put in links for you to research on.  You will have to do some reading on your part!

Comment: Thank you! I don't mind reading/learning at all :) But just to clarify, I only need to download the .bacpac file to my home system so I can upload it to my VM on a different Azure account. I'll start reading - thanks again! - Rob

Comment: Hey Crafty, Thanks for your help! I haven't read through it all yet but I was able to download the files using the other solution - it was easier for my meager brain. Great blog btw - hopefully I'll be able to take advantage of it all…thanks again…Rob

Comment: No worries, again a backup is the best way to go.  There is also Microsoft Sync but that is more technical than the two solutions here.  I just could not propose the other solution since I am no longer working with a Azure client.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the Azure Page Blob as an NTFS drive using a utility like XDrive. I'm trying to use "Azure Storage Explorer" to do the same thing but it's not allowing me access to the files inside of the VHDS file (and I think that it should). XDrive is supposed to allow for a mapped drive type feel in Windows Explorer.

Backup the databases to the secondary hard drive on the Vm's. Download, install, and configure XDrive to point to this hard drive. Grab the backups. Voila! Please note that XDrive limits read/write access to distributed enviornments so this should only be used as a tempory solution for environments not distributed (ie. load balanced) or you could cause a disruption to your production users.

XDrive: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/02/02/Using-Windows-Azure-Drive-%28aka-X-Drive%29.aspx

Updated:

1. Download "Azure Storage Explorer" from http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/
2. From the Azure portal, click on the db you want to export and from the dashboard tab, there's an "Export" button. This will create a bacpac file.
3. Choose a storage account (remember which one you chose because you will have to access it later).
4. For the container, create a new one called "DB Storage" or something like that. You will need to server credentials to do the export.
5. After the export completes, open up "Azure Storage Explorer" and add the storage account you placed the backup in. You will need the storage account name and the primary key (both can be pulled from the Azure portal). I have to use the option "HTTPS" but you may or may not.
6. Once the account is in the explorer, on the left pane you should see the new container you created in the earlier step. Click on it which should pull up your bacpac file in the middle pane.
7. Highlight the bacpac file and choose download.

It's a bit of a pain because you have to install the explorer utility but after that's done, it's really easy.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hey there, again, thanks for the suggestion but there is no VM and, even if I created one, how do I bacup the db to the hd? That's exactly what I'm looking to do…But all this seems like a lot of work just to grab a .bacpac file from one Azure account and transfer to another account. Is there no way to just download the .bacpac file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I thought the trouble was the the databases were located on a VM blob. That means the solution for you is easy!

Comment: There you go, I updated the original solution. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hey NIck - worked perfectly! In all my searching I never even came across a mention of the Azurestorageexplorer…Thank you very much! Now, you wouldn't happen to know if there's a way to export Web Sites from Azure would you? :)

Comment: I do not know how to export websites, sorry bud. Glad to hear you were able to figure this out. Could you mark this as answered? :)